# Calculating variables using ndgrid

Tags: matlab

I am building a multivariate model, where the model parameters are shown below using linspace to create a range of 10 values between two min/max:

```
v1 = linspace(v1min,v1max,10);
v2 = linspace(v2min,v2max,10);
v3 = linspace(v3min,v3max,10);
v4 = linspace(v4min,v4max,10);
v5 = linspace(v5min,v5max,10);
v6 = linspace(v6min,v6max,10);
```

**Edit:**
Here is the current state of my script, after following suggestions from @Suever and @Mad Physicist

```
[data.v1, data.v2, data.v3, data.v4, data.v5, data.v6] = ndgrid(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);
n = numel(data.v1);
data.v7 = zeros(1,n);
data.v8 = zeros(1,n);
data.v9 = zeros(1,n);

for i = 1:n
     [data.v7(i), data.v8(i), data.v9(i)] = my_function(data.v1(i), data.v2(i), data.v3(i), data.v4(i), data.v5(i), data.v6(i));
end

clearvars i n v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6;
```

Comment: How you can store 8 TB data in memory? each of data.v1 to v9 require 8 TB.

Comment: I've reduced the parameter ranges for the obvious reason that you've alluded to. I have no way to store that much data.

Comment: you can edit your question or provide more clarification

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: Instead of `length` use `numel` data.v1 is a multidimensional array

Comment: thanks, numel did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @Suever's answer, there are a couple of good reasons to use `ndgrid`. Besides the relative inefficency of using nested loops in a vectorized language, you are also reallocating each of the arrays in `data` for each of your `length(v1) * length(v2) * ...` iterations. `ndgrid` allows you to preallocate the first 6 fields of `data` in a single fast operation, then unroll all your loops into a single loop:

```
 [data.v1, data.v2, data.v3, data.v4, data.v5, data.v6] = ndgrid(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);
 n = length(data.v1);
 data.v7 = zeros(1, n);
 data.v8 = zeros(1, n);
 data.v9 = zeros(1, n);
 for i = 1:n
     [data.v7(i), data.v8(i), data.v9(i)] = my_function(data.v1(i), data.v2(i), data.v3(i), data.v4(i), data.v5(i), data.v6(i));
 end
```

If you are very lucky and `my_function` is properly vectorized, you can possibly even do this:

```
 [data.v1, data.v2, data.v3, data.v4, data.v5, data.v6] = ndgrid(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);
 [data.v7, data.v8, data.v9] = my_function(data.v1, data.v2, data.v3, data.v4, data.v5, data.v6);
```

Comment: I've updated my script per your suggestions. Not sure if the for-loop calculation is correct, as it appears that data.v3(end) and data.v3(length(data.v3)) provide different results. I don't think that the for-loop calculation is capturing the ranges correctly.

Comment: @Pete. If you are having an issue with an element of `data.v3`, that would be an issue with the parameter order in `ndgrid`, not the for loop. The loop only sets `v7-9`.

Comment: I guess I was questioning the output in general. Just to spot check I manually computed the output of my_function(v1(end), v2(end), v3(end), v4(end), v5(1), v6(1)) and the output does not match anything from the for-loop function that sets v7-9. I may not have asked the right question though

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to create all of the combinations without any loops

```
[V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6] = ndgrid(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);
```

Also, it may be worth rethinking your problem a little bit so that you aren't brute forcing your optimization by literally trying every combination.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ndgrid!

My goal is to develop sensitivity plots to show, for instance, how variables 1-6 affect variable 7.